# Unable to input UTF-16 characters in firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard, unicode, special-characters

I want to insert greek characters, via a keyboard mapping I've made, when working in firefox (and Jupyter Notebook).

I am able to use ctrl+cmd+space to add characters like

```
MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD CAPITAL PSI
Unicode: U+1D76D, UTF-8: F0 9D 9D AD
```

I am also able to copy and paste the characters in.
Firefox will also happily display characters, in files I open.

If I write the characters using the keyboard mapping, I only get two small boxes with the text D8 35 inside.

I have checked in Chrome and Safari, and they work fine, displaying the character after input. Programs like Atom and textedit also work without a hitch, so as far as I see, the issue is limited to Firefox.

When I copy the two small boxes from firefox into e.g. chrome, it renders the desired character again.

I run MacOS High Sierra, with Firefox 62.0.3. I used Ukulele 3.7.2 to create the keyboard mapping.

In jupyter, the special characters can be used as names, and I can assign values to them, etc. If I use a commandline interface to python, I'm unable to assign values to the special characters. I am however still able to write them using the keyboard mapping.

Is there a solution, or should I start getting used to Chrome instead?

Comment: Seems like the font applicable in firefox is not having these character. Check in firefox options which font and encoding is visible?

Comment: btw, this is not UTF-16. This is UTF-8